# Bing maps on Cordova

Tags: cordova, bing

I have been trying to implement BING MAPS in a Cordova App but have been unsuccessful in it.

The Bing mas doesn’t load and it always throws the exception : “0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'Microsoft' is undefined"

Same goes with google maps too. It says “0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'google' is undefined"

Any pointers?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <title>Bing Maps</title>
</head>
<body>


    <div id="divMap" style="width:100%; height:92%;
   position:absolute; left:0px; top:55px;" onload="GetMap();"></div>
</body>
</html>


<script>

    function GetMap() {



        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Themes.BingTheme', {
            callback: function () {
                map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('divMap'),
                {
                    credentials: "<BING MAP KEY>",
                    mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.road,
                    enableClickableLogo: false,
                    enableSearchLogo: false,
                    center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(47.603561, -122.329437),
                    zoom: 10,
                    theme: new Microsoft.Maps.Themes.BingTheme()
                });
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Are you using the bing javascript API? did you link the bing js? Did you whitelist the url to the online js?

Comment: I have included js files which are under Bing.Maps.JavaScript(veapicore.js and veapiModules.js) locally in the project. I have also included the js file from http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0 locally in the project. Is there something else i am missing?

Comment: Update: It is working in Windows Phone 8 emulators and not for rest of them.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/content-security-policy/

The new Cordova 5 security model prevents loading and execution of any script from any non-local source, you need to add a header tag specifically allow Cordova to load scripts from a particular source

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net; data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

most importantly it is

```
script-src 'self' http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net;
```

that allows u to load script locally(self) and from the virutalearth.net site